# can I target only background opacity and nothing else

Tags: css

I'm wondering if the following can be done.
Looking at this example http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/r7kSf/,  can only the left icons be targeted with an opacity level? To have let's say `opacity:0.5;` normal conditions and under hover to have full opacity? I know that when using a color is easier using an alpha coefficient, but what about only the image? 
The option can be to use two different icons ? load alternate version of it under hover?
I don't think that is good idea since to many http requests unless in a sprite or so..

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but requires some tricky CSS3 hacking - basically, creating a new inline-block element in front of each item using the `:before` pseudo-element, and then adjusting the opacity for such elements. Also, instead of assigning the background-image to the `<li>` element itself, you will assign it to the `:before` pseudo-element instead.

```
#mainFeatures li:before {
    content: '\0000a0';
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 30px;
}

#mainFeatures li#[insert element ID here]:before { 
    background:url([image url]) no-repeat 0 5px;
}
```

I have modified and forked your fiddle - check it out :) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/QBGWf/1/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use CSS3's `rgba` background. For example, `#F7F8BD` with 50% opacity becomes `rgba(247,248,189,0.5);` Note that the compatibility is not yet 100%, so use the following:

```
background: #F7F8BD; /* Browsers that don't support RGBa */
rgba(247,248,189,0.5); /* CSS3 */
```

See http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
opacity:0.5
```

use:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

where the first 3 numbers are the red, green and blue values, the last one is the alpha value, which gives transparency to your background

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question then no - you can't apply opacity to the bullet image but not to the whole `li`.

Your best option is to put the image in as a background to a `span`:

```
<li><span class="bg"></span> Text</li>
```

And apply the opacity to the `span`

Comment: Good - then please mark it as the accepted answer. You need to do this for all your previous questions too, so that people continue to take the time to offer you their help.